# Issue when checking URL containing %20

Tags: url, validation

I have custom control which displays different details depending on which site the user is currently at. My problem is that as soon as the URL contains non-alphabetic characters, the controls fails to show any details at all.

Works: http://myserver/subsiteone

Doesn't work: http://myserver/subsite%20two

Snippet of my code

```
private enum Investor { None, Ventures, Growth, Seeds }
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    var investor = CheckUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb().Url);

    switch (investor)
    {
        case Investor.None:
            Controls.Add("Some data");
            break;
        case Investor.Ventures:
            Controls.Add("Some data");
            break;
        case Investor.Growth:
            Controls.Add("Some data");
            break;
        case Investor.Seeds:
            Controls.Add("Some data");
            break;
    }
}

private static Investor CheckUrl(string url)
{
    return url.Contains("Ventures") ? Investor.Ventures : (url.Contains("Growth%20Samples") ? Investor.Growth : (url.Contains("Seeds") ? Investor.Seeds : Investor.None));
}
```

As you can see, when I check on Investor.Growth the URL should contain Growth%20Samples, and it does but the code somehow doesn't approve of it as valid and skips on.

How can I prevent this from happening, since it approves the other parameters which have nothing but alphabetic characters in them?

**EDIT**: This is continuous development on an existing site with tons of subsites, lists etc so a recreation of the site is not possible at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution to this.

```
const string growth = "Growth Sample";
var xEncode = SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(growth); 
url.Contains(xEncode) // Taken out of context
```

I don't know why url.Contains("Growth%20Samples") didn't work, as `SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode` gives the exact same output.

Anyhow, enjoy!